# How the rank function works in R

Tags: r, ranking

Comrades! Please teach.
How the rank function works in R. I would like to understand exactly the formula and logic by which the function gets the result. For example, independently post it in Excel
I don't really understand, for example, how do I get such a result and how to get it myself without using the function.

```
> rank(c(1,10,1))
[1] 1.5 3.0 1.5
```

I am sure that there are those who can explain using simple mathematics

Comment: From [`?rank`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rank.html): *"ties.method: a character string specifying how ties are treated"*.

Comment: As for *"get it myself without using the function"*, I don't think I'll go down the road of how to re-implement base R functions: it uses internal code (`.Internal(rank(...))`), which means several things (e.g., compiled).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, there are 3 numbers: 1,10,1

you sort them from smallest to greatest and assign a rank:

- 1 - rank 1
- 1 - rank 2
- 10 - rank 3

but 1 and 1 are the same - so the `ties.method` is being applied. Default method is `"average"`, therefore ranks 1 and 2 are averaged -  `(1+2)/2=1.5`

if you change your vector and do `rank(c(1,10,10))`, you'll get `1.0 2.5 2.5`:

- 1 - rank 1
- 10 - rank 2
- 10 - rank 3

rank 2 and rank 3 are averaged: `(2+3)/2=2.5`

you can check the documentation for other `ties.method`, for instance `min` would take a smallest rank of duplicate:

```r
rank(c(1,10,1),ties.method='min')
[1] 1 3 1
```